# What is this "part" in the charger and what is its use?

Tags: charger

The charger for my ASUS laptop haves this part [image: this part],
but I don't know what it is, what it is called and what it is use for. Can somebody tell me what this is and what it is for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you wrap the cable up, you can clip that to another part of the cable to keep it neat.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing or weighing  it, it is entirely PROBABLE that its just a clip to keep it neat, however it is also possible that (in addition to keeping the cables neat) it contains a [ferrite bead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) to filter out high frequency noise.

Comment: I agree that its a clip since I can attach the wire to it but I think it's not a ferrite bread since in the images I saw, it is too small to be one. But, thanks!